# Can't get Spark to work on IPython Notebook in Windows

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, pyspark

I have installed spark on a Windows 10 box, and the installation works fine from the Pyspark console. But recently I have tried to configure Ipython Notebook to work with the Spark installation. I have made the following imports

```
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "E:/Spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6"
sys.path.append("E:/Spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin")
sys.path.append("E:/Spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python")
sys.path.append("E:/Spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark")
sys.path.append("E:/Spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib")
sys.path.append("E:/Spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip")
sys.path.append("E:/Spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-    src.zip")
sys.path.append("C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_51/bin")
```

This works fine for creating the SparkContext and also for code like

```
sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])
```

But when I write the following

```
file = sc.textFile("E:/scripts.sql")
words = sc.count()
```

I get the following error

```
Py4JJavaError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-3c172daac960> in <module>()
 1 file = sc.textFile("E:/scripts.sql")
 ----> 2 file.count()

 E:/Spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python\pyspark\rdd.py in count(self)
 1002         3
 1003         """
 -> 1004         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
 1005 
 1006     def stats(self):

 E:/Spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python\pyspark\rdd.py in sum(self)
 993         6.0
 994         """
 --> 995         return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
 996 
 997     def count(self):

 E:/Spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python\pyspark\rdd.py in fold(self, zeroValue, op)
 867         # zeroValue provided to each partition is unique from the one provided
 868         # to the final reduce call
 --> 869         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
 870         return reduce(op, vals, zeroValue)
 871 

 E:/Spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python\pyspark\rdd.py in collect(self)
 769         """
 770         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
 --> 771             port =     self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
 772         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
 773 

 E:\Spark\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
 811         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
 812         return_value = get_return_value(
 --> 813             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
 814 
 815         for temp_arg in temp_args:

 E:\Spark\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
 306                 raise Py4JJavaError(
 307                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
 --> 308                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
309             else:
310                 raise Py4JError(Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling     z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 8, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker did not connect back in time at   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:131)
... 12 more

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:405)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker did not connect back in time
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:131)
... 12 more
```

Please help resolve this as I am on a short time project.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the backslashes.

```
file = sc.textFile("E:\\scripts.sql")
```

*Edited to add a second item to look at:*

Also, I notice you called:

```
words = sc.count()
```

Try this instead, which worked on my Windows 10 install:

```
file = sc.textFile("E:/scripts.sql")
words = file.count()
```

Comment: Already tried that but to no avail. I think the pertinent error lies in the error info `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker did not connect back in time`

Comment: @Maurer Still no way forward. I updated ipython notebook to jupyter but to no avail. The error still starts as ...

    `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.`